# WordPress: set body class of a specific template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I created a specific template for one page only = I don't want it to be listed in the admin section. So I removed the "Template name" from the comment and let WP figure it out by the slug of the post. That works. Now I would like to assign a custom body class for this template only (as I do with every page) in my functions file:

```
function cc_set_body_classes($classes) {
    switch(true) {
        case is_page_template("page-about-us.php"):
            $classes[] = "about-us";
            break;
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter("body_class", "cc_set_body_classes");
```

Now this would obviously work just fine if it wasn't a specific template without the Template name. Is it possible to figure out the template name if no Template name is specified in the comments? How should I do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? It looks fine (except for the odd use of `switch`).

Comment: @rnevius is_page_template is not working for specific templates. At least it seems so.

Comment: Are those templates in sub-directories?

Comment: They are not. It works fine IF I give them (or well, it) a template name. But I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always check the page slug (since that's what you've used to define the template name in the first place). Something like the following should work:

```
function cc_set_body_classes($classes) {
    if ( get_queried_object()->post_name === "about-us" ) {
        $classes[] = "about-us";
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter("body_class", "cc_set_body_classes");
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Just out of curiosity - how would you actually get the template of the page?

Comment: That's a little more difficult, since WordPress pages often render multiple templates simultaneously. However, I recommend taking a look at [this question on WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file) for more info.